# Dois sites em um so domínio

Tags: wordpress, magento, seo

Olá, eu gostaria de desenvolver dois sites, sendo um dele institucional e o outro uma loja virtual. Mas eu gostaria de utilizar o mesmo domínio. Logo penso que ficará assim: 
Quando alguém escrever **www.meusite.com.br**, ela será redirecionada automaticamente para **www.meusite.com.br/institucional**. (Pois desejo que quando ela digitar ela seja redirecionada para o institucional), e no institucional haverão links para que a pessoa vá à loja que aí a home da loja será: **www.meusite.com.br/loja**.
Logo, não haverá nada em www.meusite.com.br.

Gostaria de saber se ambos os sites (**www.meusite.com.br/institucional** e **www.meusite.com.br/loja**) irão aparecer no SEO do google, sendo que estes são do mesmo domínio.
E quais seriam as possível soluções para o meu problema.
Obs: O site da loja será magento e estará na pasta raíz, e o institucional é um subdiretório que utilizará wordpress.
Agradeço desde já.

Comment: O google é (meio que) agnóstico quanto à tecnologia usada para montar um site, portanto, vai indexar tudo dentro de www.meusite.com.br , se você fizer um bom trabalho de indexação. Isso independe de como as páginas são construídas. Se você quer um trabalho de SEO diferente para cada uma delas, e mais direcionado, eu recomendaria o uso de subdominios, tipo loja.meusite.com.br, mas aí é outra história

Comment: Você pode desenvolver utilizando Wordpress com Woocommerce, assim, você terá o institucional e a loja rodando no mesmo dominio e na mesma plataforma. So nao acho necessario o `/institucional/` essa parte institucional do site pode ficar na raiz mesmo, tipo, ao acessar `meusite.com.br` a pessoa ver o institucional e quando acessar `/loja/` ver a loja